# Spanish for “sink”

Tags: vocabulario

I have come across at least 2 words: **pila** and **fregadero**. Do they really mean exactly the same thing or are there any subtle differences? Can they also be used for the *washbowl* that is not in the kitchen? Are there any other words in Spanish for the *sink* or *washbowl* or *wash-basin*?

Comment: Some other words that come to mind are *lavamanos* and *lavabo*, but I'm sure there are a ton more--just as there are in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are ok, it depends on where are located at your house.

**Pila** is according to RAE:

> Pieza grande de piedra o de otra materia, cóncava y profunda, donde cae o se echa el agua para varios usos.

And **fregadero** is a pila where to wash/clean. According to RAE:

> Pila de fregar.

In Spain *fregadero* can be outdoors at a terrace for example when you are speaking about the one you use to clean your clothers so you will hang the clothes out to dry, or the *fregadero* inside the kitchen used to wash/clean your plates.

*Pila* is in the bathroom.

About washbowl is *palangana*

Comment: We use pileta in argentina for sink and lavamanos in the bathroom.

Comment: In Cuba we use **pila** just for the spigot (no matter where it is placed), and **fregadero** just for the sink in the kitchen.

Answer (score 6):

I guess this is very region dependent. I understand "fregadero" because of dubbings, but in my neck of the woods (Argentina) nobody ever says "fregadero"; here it's "pileta de lavar" (or just "pileta"); "bacha" is also used.

Answer (score 3):

In Mexico, equivalents of the word **sink** (meaning the bowl where the dishes are washed) are **tarja** and **fregadero**. There is no difference whether it is indoors or outdoors; it usually has one or two bowls and made of metal or porcelain.

**Lavadero** is a stone made piece used to wash clothes (Mexico.) Usually a **lavadero** has a **pila** attached.

**Pila/pileta** is an uncovered stone piece made with the purpose of storing water; usually to wash something but this is not a must (its use meaning **sink** is also regional.) Another meaning for **pila/pileta** is **pool** (also regional.)

**Lavabo/lavamanos** is usually in the bathroom or just outside the bathroom and used to wash ones hands. It is commonly made of porcelain, but other materials can also be used.

**Palangana** can have different regional meanings but in Mexico is a portable water container (i.e. is not attached to buildings.) It can be made of plastic or metal.

The water storage for buildings is called **aljibe/cisterna** if it is underground; **tinaco** if it is elevated or placed on the rooftop. These are usually covered because they store clean water.

Answer (score 2):

In Colombia we refer to a sink as **lavaplatos**,  the place where dishes are washed,  instead of a device to wash dishes,  to which we refer as **maquina lavaloza**.

Answer (score 1):

In Spain `fregadero` is the one you have in your kitchen and you use to wash your dishes. Although `pila` can be understood as a synonym of `fregadero`, Spaniards would favor the latter.

> Qué quieres que haga con estos platos?
>
> Déjalos en la pila / Déjalos en el fregadero

"Pila" is a concave and deep piece of stone (or steel or other material) where you put water for different uses. You could find a "pila" in a church (known as *pila bautismal*). Also, note that when you are asking somebody to "dejar los platos en la pila" it could also have the double meaning of "leave them in the **stack**", if you are putting plates on top of each other in order to be washed.

Spaniards tend to use the word `lavabo` to refer to the [sink in the bathroom](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavabo) (where you would wash your hands). You could also hear "la pila del baño", to refer to "lavabo", but again most people would favor "lavabo" over "pila". "lavabo" is also how the bathroom can be know when it doesn't have a shower or bath (has just the sink and a toilet). Most bathrooms in Spain have a [`bidé` (to wash other things)](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bid%C3%A9). A *bidé* could be understood as another *pila*, but it receives that name (etymology from the French *bidet*, the name of a breed of small horses).

Answer (score 0):

In Tijuana, México we call the kitchen sink **fregadero**. And the bathroom sink **lavamanos** or **lavabo**.

Being so close to the border we also use the americanized terms **sink de la cocina** and **sink del baño**.

Answer (score 0):

- Bathroom sink: *lavamanos or lavabo*.
- Kitchen sink: *lavatrastes or fregadero*.
- Dishwasher (machine): *el lavaplatos*.